# what doles /webhp instead of /search in the url do when performing a search?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently noticed that the url in my address bar was something like `https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en` instead of the usual `/search`.

I was wondering what the significance of this was and what /webhp is.